# Error: could not find function "glimpse"

Tags: r

I am trying to use glimpse function in R as below

```
df<- read.csv("movie-pang02.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
glimpse(df)
```

But I am getting the error:

Error: could not find function "glimpse"

Could anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 7):

You'll need the `dplyr` package installed, first. Also, you need to have the `glimpse` call on a separate line.

```
library(dplyr)
glimpse(mtcars)
```

Answer (score 0):

Install and load Package dplyr
library(dplyr)

Answer (score 0):

First, You'll need the tibble package installed. Also, you need to have the glimpse call on a separate line

```r
library(tibble)
glimpse(mpg)
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me.

I was able to make it work by installing the pillar package :

`install.packages("pillar")`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you run `library(dplyr)` first then run the `glimpse()` function.

Comment: how does this add to the previous (April 13) answer?